# Can I know a file extension if y only have the name and it path

Tags: java, android, file-io

I have an objects that one of its attribute is the Image ID.
The images are saved on a folder and their names are their ids.
Some of the images are jpg files, others png files and some are just the name without an extension.
My question is if there is a way to know the extension if I only know where are they stored and its names.

```
private void LoadImagenArticulo(Articulo articulo, ImageView imageViewControl)
{
    try {
        if(articulo == null)
            imageViewControl.setImageResource(R.drawable.articulo_no_encontrado);
        else
        {
            String imagePath = Fachada.getInstance().getImageFolder();
            if(imagePath != null && !imagePath.equals(""))
            {

                String pathName = imagePath + "/img" + articulo.getIdImagen(); 
                File image = new File(pathName);

                if(image.exists())
                {
                    Bitmap imageBitmap = UtilsUI.decodeFile(image);
                    if(imageBitmap != null)
                        imageViewControl.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
                }
                else
                    imageViewControl.setImageResource(R.drawable.articulo_sin_imagen);

            }
            else
                imageViewControl.setImageResource(R.drawable.articulo_sin_imagen);


        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w("Exception", e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: If you know the filename what's wrong with getting everything after the last `.`?

Comment: What should hapen if two images have the same name but different extensions? 123.jpg and 123.png, for example.

Comment: @KevinWorkman that is not possible because the image id is unique.

Comment: @Cruncher When I check without the file extension "image.exists()" return me false.

Comment: @user3177273 if ids are unique, can't you just loop through the directory and create a map from ids to image files? Alternatively, you could check whether any of the possible extensions exists.

Answer (score 0):

There are tools that can check the actual filetype basing on its content. try this: [Java Mime Magic](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmimemagic/).

edit:
I've found a simpler solution:

```
public static String getContentType(File file) throws IOException {
    return Files.probeContentType(file.toPath());
}
```

However I haven't tested all filetypes.